# Artifacts when using custom view inside NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa

I have a scroll view that shows a number of custom views.

In that custom view I use my own class so I can use the drawRect method to draw a line at the bottom of the view.

```
@interface MyListItemView : NSView
```

Here is my implementation of drawRect

```
@implementation MyListItemView

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

    NSBezierPath * path;
    path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint: rect.origin];
    [path lineToPoint: NSMakePoint(rect.size.width, 0)];

    [path setLineWidth:1];

    [[NSColor grayColor] set]; 
    [path stroke];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}

@end
```

This draws the line as expected, but when I scroll the container I get artifacts appearing, like shown on the right hand side of the image below:

[image: Screen shot of artifact lines on my app]

I tried saving and restoring the graphics context, but this made no difference and it doesn't look like that code is required. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspiration hit me while on a walk.

I'm drawing a line on the very edge of my view. It looks like some of that is getting drawn just outside the view (possibly due to anti aliasing) and isn't getting cleaned up properly.

All I needed to do was move my line up by half a pixel, changing my line code to this:

```
[path moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 0.5)];
[path lineToPoint: NSMakePoint(rect.size.width, 0.5)];
```